# SharePoint 2007 stopped recording of messages into log files

Tags: 2007, logging

May I know what should I do if the MOSS 2007 stop recording message into the logs located in the C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\LOGS folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [How to disable logging in Windows Sharepoint Services V3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisfie/archive/2006/12/10/how-to-disable-logging-in-windows-sharepoint-services-v3.aspx) 
(Just verify your settings there don't disable it). Also check available disk space.

Comment: Thanks. I double-check the settings and found that the logging setting is still "on" and the disk space is still sufficient. I re-check the log files and was shocked to see something - there are two log files - one is 12:XX PM while another one is 12:XX AM and both files is today date. I feel shocked is because the time 12:XX PM for today has not reached and the log file appeared. (Gosh, am I too tried or the computer playing with me?) Anyway, managed to find the correct log file and all are working.